# Duplicate entries to mongoDB using mongoose - no idea why

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, insert

So I'm working on a project in school, and am responsible with another classmate for the mongodb functionality of saving a webhook from github's API to mongoose. Sound's simple enought right? Pff.

It worked just fine when working with sample data, saved in a JSON file. The testing went fine and so all seemed good. But when we were to merge our part with the work of others, i.e instead of working with a JSON file creating an object (issueCommentObject) for each comment, the db started to act in peculiar ways, saving first the initial comment, then the intial comment and the second comment (totaling in 3), and so forth. I.e duplicates. But with new ID's for each insert.

We have logged every variable possible it seems, spent hours upon hrs of debugging, searching the web but cannot get it to behave differently. To make matters worse, we have a meeting tomorrow in which we are supposed to demo the work of this and previous iteration(s). Please help us!

-- Code snippets --

In index

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){
if(req.body.action == issueComment)
{
    console.log("Issue COMMENTED");
    let issueCommentObject = {};
    console.log(issueCommentObject)
    issueCommentObject.action = issueComment;
    issueCommentObject.issue_title = req.body.issue.title;              `   `       //Title of issue
    issueCommentObject.issue_owner = req.body.issue.user.login;                 `      `//Owner of issue
    issueCommentObject.issue_status = req.body.issue.state;             `       `       //State of issue
    issueCommentObject.issue_milestone = req.body.issue.milestone;      //No     milestone = 0 null
    issueCommentObject.issue_totalComments = req.body.issue.comments;   `    `       //Total comments
    issueCommentObject.issue_commentBody = req.body.comment.body;        `  `       //The actual comments value
    issueCommentObject.issue_commenter = req.body.sender.login;         `  `        `      `//Who did the comment.
    issueCommentObject.organization = req.body.organization.login;
     //console.log(req.body)
      responseHandler.saveIssueComment(issueCommentObject)
```

In responseHandler:

```
    saveIssue: function (issueJSON) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        responseHandler.dbHandler.handle(function () {
                var newIssue = responseHandler.issuesModel(issueJSON);
                if(newIssue.issue_title){
                    newIssue.save(function(err) {
                    if(err) resolve("testSaveIssueWithValid responded with - " +err);
                        console.log("issue saved".green)
                        resolve("issue saved");
                    });
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Wrong input".red)
                    resolve("issue not saved");
                }           

            //responseHandler.dbHandler.disconnect()
            });

    })

},
```

Function sent as param to dbhandler is called on db open:

```
 handle: function(callback)
{
   var db = dbHandler.mongoose.connection;
    console.log("db.readyState: "+ db.readyState)
    //if disconnected, connect to the database
    if(db.readyState == 0)
    {
        console.log("Connectin hoj".rainbow)
        dbHandler.connect();
    }

    console.log("db.readyState: "+db.readyState)
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

    // If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection 
    ..
   db.on('open', callback);     
 }
/*
*   connects if mongoose connection
*   @return void
*/
connect: function()
{
    console.log("conn")
    var options = {     
        server: {
                    //keepalive in milliseconds
                    //http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html
                    options: { keepAlive: 3000 }
                },  
    }

    dbHandler.mongoose.connect(dbHandler.dbHost);
},

disconnect: function () {
    dbHandler.mongoose.disconnect()
    console.log("responseHandler.dbHandler.mongoose.disconnect()   ed")
    // body...
}
```

The schema model for issues

```
var responseSchema = new Schema({

name: String,
organisation: String,
repo: String,
response: String
});

var response = mongoose.model('response', responseSchema);
```

Comment: I can't tell based on your code, but going by the `db.on("open")` part, it seems to me like you're opening a new connection to the database every call. Connections don't close unless you tell them to close. So if you aren't telling it to close, each connection you create is processing `.save()`.

Comment: Updatated code snippets to include connect/disconnect functionality aswell. We know, but still didn't work. /OP

Comment: You shouldn't be opening and closing the connection. You should open it prior to even spinning up the server. The entire server should be wrapped in the db connection, and this issue would likely disappear.

Comment: Intresting, please expand upon that, we don't quite understand how one would do that in practice :)

Comment: Here's a [very simple gist](https://gist.github.com/cdbajorin/17858ecc59b8f28d31ef) of what I'm talking about. When asking questions like these, I recommend creating new (and very simple) code that recreates your problem. The act of creating the new code is debugging in and of itself, and usually helps you find the issue.